# Polymorphism on repository interface for local and remote operations

Tags: design, design-patterns, dependency-injection, polymorphism

I'm in the process of designing a facade `ApiClient` class that would abstract some CRUD operations between a local database and a remote one (through a REST web app).

Said `ApiClient` class depends on 2 other implementation classes (let's call them `local repo` and `remote repo`, whose responsibilities are to interact with the local database driver and with an http client, respectively.

That being said, some resources (let's call it `ResourceA`) are to be saved locally after being retrieved from the network, but it cannot be saved TO the network. An example of this would be the retrieval of a list of `ResourceA` and save each item locally, but there is no creation of `ResourceA` nor update it to the server-side.

Up to this point, the `local repo` should implement a `save(ResourceA)` operation, but `remote repo` shouldn't.

So the question is: should those 2 classes be an implementation of 2 different interfaces (`local repo interface` and `remote repo interface`), or both of them should implement a single interface, but on `save` operation `remote repo` should throw an `invalid operation exception`?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from the question if remote repo doesn't support add/update operations at all or only for specific types. In case of the first option, I would go with 2 interfaces: IReadonlyRepo, IWritableRepo. In case of the second option, I would go with the exception approach.